# PHP 7 CLI: is there any method to skip undefined functions?

Tags: php, error-handling, tokenize, php-7

**Scenario** I have a very large php file, it has numerous calls to different functions. 
This  file is normally executed within a 'complex' MVC, so all objects, methods, functions are defined higher somewhere else.

I am writing a crude PHP script, to be executed from PHP CLI, that will directly include this other file.

I don't care about anything inside the file, except the call to one particular function

```
example($string);
```

I want to define example() in my new script to do something basic, in this case log to a file. e.g.

```
example($string){
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $string, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

I cannot simply find the original definition of example(), add my new code there,  and execute the whole application as normal, because example() is called all over the place, and I really just want to target this one particular file.

**Question**
Is there any way to force PHP to continue executing on undefined functions? I don't want to wrap all instance of other functions in try catch, (original file should not be modified at all). I have tried `set_exception_handler` and some other way of modifying exception handling in .ini, and although I can customize this, PHP still halts execution of the script when throwing the custom exception.

Currently I am creating dummy functions in my CLI script

```
 function already_defined_function(){
      return null; 
   }
```

Since this generates warnings only. This is tedious and breaks quickly when i try and target a large number of files.

I am curious if there is an abstract way to suppress any and all undefined methods / functions / class instantiations. I presently believe it's not possible.

I have tried loading the PHP file as text/string, and then using tokenizer to get something like this:

```
[1094] => Array
    (
        [0] => 319
        [1] => example
        [2] => 172
    )

[1095] => (
[1096] => Array
    (
        [0] => 323
        [1] => 'example string parameter example'
        [2] => 172
    )

[1097] => )
[1098] => ;
```

I could then loop through this array and reassemble the function call. But i'm not clear if things like additional arguments, breaking spaces etc are going to change the number of array items which compose one 'complete' function call.

Comment: Why not just `include` the file containing the function definition?

Comment: Because I am redefining that function definition in the script. The other files which define other 'unneeded' functions span across several hundred files.

Comment: So, let me see if I have this right. You want to use your own definition of `example()`, not the existing one. Okay. But if you're not including the file where that's defined, what's the problem? You would just do `function example(...) {...}` like you would for any other function, and there wouldn't be an error. What am I missing here?

Comment: the problem is not with example() itself, it's with all the other functions which are not example(), and which PHP is attempting to execute when I include the file, and thus fatal errors are thrown.

Comment: So, you *do* want those other functions to be defined? If that's the issue, I might be able to help you, but I need to be sure I understand the question.

Comment: yes i suppose that's one way of looking at it. I was thinking more, 'if function is not defined, continue execution of the script istead of throwing fatal error'. But some way to dynamically define other functions which are not example() at runtime should work as well...(is that possible!?)

Comment: well, simply pretending those functions weren't called and carrying on as if nothing happened is problematic; you're ignoring whatever those functions do. I have a solution, though I will have to type it up on my computer and test a couple things, so I'll share it in a little bit (probably about an hour).

Comment: i vote for just bad idea, dont even think about this approach, but that may just be me

Comment: I agree about why you would say it's a bad idea, it's not an approach I would ever consider using for a robust application. This is more a helper utility I'm going to use and throw away. I suppose a better approach would be to treat the file as string, and explore parsing via regex or tokenizer. However It got me thinking about the nature of of error handling in PHP, and how to explore controlling that.

Comment: @baku Well, never mind. My idea didn't work. I don't have any good suggestions for you that don't involve either (1) writing your code in such a way that you don't need to include whatever file is calling the function in question in the first place (making your script more standalone) or (2) parsing PHP files on the fly. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

PHP7 now allows you to catch most errors.  This should work:

```
try {
    undefinedfunc('Hello World');
}
catch (Error $e) {
    echo "Error caught\n";
}
echo "Reached\n";
```

I just say you don't want to wrap your calls in try catch blocks, but I believe it would the correct way to handle something like this.

I think a good alternative for this would be writing your own caller, like so:

```
function call_and_catch_function($name, $arguments) {
   try {
       return call_user_func_array($name, $arguments);
   }
   catch (Error $e) {
       // Do something
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, devon, I agree this would be the correct way to handle this if I was modifying the original application/file. For the sake of this scenario let's assume I cannot, or that's it's impractical.

Comment: I added a little extra, I'll leave this here for other readers.